# Make an object reference of an existing Literal in the aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, object-reference

How can I make an object reference of a Literal that I have declared in the aspx page. 
Now I use it as `ltlContents.Text = .....` but I need to make a reference of that `ltlContents` so I can use it in a static method the same way I use it with its `.Text` attribute.

I tried something like `Literal ltl = ...` but this is new for me, as it's different from the usual object referencing, as it comes from the front-end.

**UPDATE:** I want to use the ltlContents object in a static method like this: `ltlContents.Text = valueFromSomeFunction`, but the compiler gives me the following error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property _Default.ltlContents`.

Comment: `ltlContents` is already an object in your code-behind. What problem are you seeing, specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to the control or the page where this control is sitting in. This page must be running though an actual lifecycle. So for example from a webmethod you cannot access a control.

However, then you can access this control even from a static method, which seems to be what you want:

```
public static void SetControlText(string controlID, string text) 
{ 
   Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
   if (page != null)
   {
      Control ctrl = FindControlRecursive(page, controlID);
      if(ctrl != null)
      {
          ITextControl txt = ctrl as ITextControl;
          if(txt != null)
              txt.Text = text;
      }
   }
}

public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id) return root;
    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
        if (t != null) return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now this works from everywhere during the lifefycle of a page:

```
SetControlText("ltlContents", "Hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since for every request a new object of your page is provided as response (their html).
So it is not possible to do it.
Instead of using that `literal` to the function make function return a value from your function and use it. Or use the value of literal to function.